# How to print to HTML Template

Tags: html, go

**How to print to HTML Template in Go?**
source: https://github.com/timpalpant/go-iex

I must be missing a lot in the go code and in the html template.

I am looking for a way to solve the issue by printing the values to an HTML template:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"

  "net/http"

  "github.com/timpalpant/go-iex"
)

func process(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  client := iex.NewClient(&http.Client{})

  quotes, err := client.GetTOPS([]string{"AAPL", "SPY"})
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  var s string
  for _, quote := range quotes {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%v: bid $%.02f (%v shares), ask $%.02f (%v shares) [as of %v]\n",
      quote.Symbol, quote.BidPrice, quote.BidSize,
      quote.AskPrice, quote.AskSize, quote.LastUpdated)
  }
  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("test.html")
  quote := s
  t.Execute(w, quote)

}

func main() {

  server := http.Server{
    Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
  }
  http.HandleFunc("/process", process)
  server.ListenAndServe()

}
```

This is the HMTL Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Go Web Programming</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
    {{ range . }}
      <li>{{ . }}</li>
    {{ end}}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

> ./web.go:22:5: s declared and not used

Comment: at line 27, column 12, the variable `s` is undefined. `s` exists only within the scope of the loop. you need to declare it within the outer scope, the process function body.

Comment: tried adding multiple variables  global scope and still the ./web.go:22:5: s declared and not used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your `for` loop, you're redeclaring `s` as a new loop-scoped variable by using `s :=`, as shown below in your code. You never use that particular variable within its scope, hence the error: `s declared and not used`.

```
// this instance of s is scoped to the function
var s string
for _, quote := range quotes {
  // *** this instance of s is only scoped to loop and it's not actually used within loop ***//
  s := fmt.Sprintf("%v: bid $%.02f (%v shares), ask $%.02f (%v shares) [as of %v]\n",
    quote.Symbol, quote.BidPrice, quote.BidSize,
    quote.AskPrice, quote.AskSize, quote.LastUpdated)
}
```

Instead, change `s :=` to this `s =`, as shown below. **However, you're still not done, read further below.**

```
var s string
for _, quote := range quotes {
  s = fmt.Sprintf("%v: bid $%.02f (%v shares), ask $%.02f (%v shares) [as of %v]\n",
    quote.Symbol, quote.BidPrice, quote.BidSize,
    quote.AskPrice, quote.AskSize, quote.LastUpdated)
}
```

**Using the code above would overwrite the value of `s` for each iteration of the loop**. If you want to keep each string generated in the loop and print them all to the template, create a slice of strings and append to it...

```
// Create s as a slice of string
var s []string
for _, quote := range quotes {
  // append each result from loop to slice
  s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%v: bid $%.02f (%v shares), ask $%.02f (%v shares) [as of %v]\n",
    quote.Symbol, quote.BidPrice, quote.BidSize,
    quote.AskPrice, quote.AskSize, quote.LastUpdated)) 
}
```

Here is the output in html template, which now includes all values from the `s` slice...

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining s in your process function.

```
  var s string
  for _, quote := range quotes {
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%v: bid $%.02f (%v shares), ask $%.02f (%v shares) [as of %v]\n",
      quote.Symbol, quote.BidPrice, quote.BidSize,
      quote.AskPrice, quote.AskSize, quote.LastUpdated)
   // ****************REMOVE s:= from here.**********
  }
```

Example:

```
func main() {
    s := ""
    items := []int{1}
    for _, quote := range items {
        s = "1"
        fmt.Println(quote)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```